# Create User who can access DB from any IP (Postgresql 9.4)

Tags: postgresql, ip-address, remote-access

I would like to create a user who can access the DB from any IP I am currently creating users as follows.

```
CREATE USER Tony@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Is there some way to alter this to create such a user?

Comment: That statement is not valid for Postgres, so you are **not** "creating users as follows". What _exactly_ are you doing?

Answer (score 4):

A user in Postgres is independent of the IP address from where the connect is made.

Access restrictions per IP address are defined in an earlier step through the network configuration defined in `pg_hba.conf`

So if you don't have any restrictions in `pg_hba.conf` then creating a user, using:

```
create user tony with password 'password';
```

will allow a login from everywhere (again: *if* `pg_hba.conf` is configured correctly).

For details on how to configure `pg_hba.conf` please see the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html

Answer (score -3):

You may use "*" for host as in :

```
CREATE USER Tony@* IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: Oh sorry… It's a MySQL syntax.
I think (but I'm absolutely not sure) in PostgreSQL, it's just : 

    CREATE USER Tony IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Well I think you've already tried it :x